# Cocycle conditions of fibre bundles

Tags: differential-geometry

In a classical approach of fibre bundle one always need the cocycle condition is satisfied, namely:
$$g_{12} g_{23} g_{31}\equiv 1$$
in $U_1\cap U_2\cap U_3$. However, I do not see why this cocycle condition cannot be succinctly stated as $g_{12} g_{21}=1$. It seems to me that I can still reassemble the original bundle without any problem arises. What is the significance of bringing in the intersection of three sets? I guess maybe I have omitted some important details but I do not see where it is.

My thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether you're talking about the cocycle condition for $0$-cochains or for $1$-cochains. Review the construction of transition functions and Čech cochains and coboundaries.